# Is it possible to have vim run a command every time save `:w` is invoked?

Tags: command-line, filetype, save, command

I am editting typescript now, and I'd like to be able to have it so, whenever `:w` is invoked, the shell runs `tsc` compiling my new save.

This beats having to `!tsc` every time.

Does something like this exist? A build or toolchain command is also an acceptable answer, as long as it can be done in one short command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does something like this exist?

In Vim this is called an autocommand. The relevant help topic can be found by typing `:h autocommand` (sic!)

An example code to put into vimrc:

```
augroup typescript_save | au!
    autocmd BufWritePost *.ts !tsc <afile>:p:S
augroup end
```

Comment: `:S` does not escape characters which are special on Vim's command-line such as `%` or `#`.
You probably want `shellescape()` and pass it a second non-zero argument: `exe '!tsc '..shellescape(expand('<afile>:p'), 1)`. Or better yet, use `system()` instead of `:!`: `call system('tsc '..expand('<afile>:p:S'))`. In that case, `:S` is reliable.

Comment: @user938271 In fact, the whole problem was due to `execute` which does superfluous cmdline-special substitution. But `execute` is totally unnecessary here.

Comment: It was not `:exe` which performed these substitutions, but `:!`. But indeed, the new command is reliable because Vim doesn't process special characters after expanding `<afile>`. In the original command, `expand()` could cause an issue because it expanded `<afile>` before `:!` is processed, and the latter expands special characters such as `%`, `#`, `!`, `<cword>`, ...